# Drag and drop to other applications and OS?

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx-2

I'm using JavaFX's [Drag and Drop system](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm) in my application, and it has been working well so far.

Now I want to support drag and drop to outside applications, eg. dragging files from my application to the explorer. How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've achieved what you described by using:

```
Vector<File> files = new Vector<File>();
private ClipboardContent filesToCopyClipboard = new ClipboardContent();

...

final ObjectWithAReturnablePathField draggableObj = new ObjectWithAReturnablePathField();

...

draggableObj.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
{

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent me) 
    {
        Dragboard db = draggableObj.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
        try 
        {
           File f = new File(new URI(draggableObj.getFilePath()));
           files.add(f);
           filesToCopyClipboard.putFiles(files);
        } 
        catch (URISyntaxException e) 
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.setContent(filesToCopyClipboard);
        me.consume();
    }

 });
 draggableObj.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() 
 {
     @Override 
     public void handle(DragEvent me) 
     {

        me.consume();
      }
 });
```

Which means:

It's possible to achieve file transference between JavaFX 2 and a native application by filling a ClipboardContent with a list using the TransferMode.ANY on the setOnDragDetected method of any Draggable Object (Any Node) which can return a Path for a file. In my case, I've created a class called Thumb extending ImageView and (among others things) I made a method called getFilePath() which returns the Path from the Image used to initialize the ImageView(). I'm sorry BTW for the poor example and the poor english, but I'm running out of time to give a more detailed answer as of now. I hope it helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the example. However, it only puts the file in the clipboard. There is no indication to the native application or system that those files should be copied or handled in any way, and the setOnDragDone's DragEvent returns null when you call getGestureTarget instead of a more useful information, like the directory you dragged the file to (if you drag a file to the system explorer for instance).

Comment: When you use the TransferMode.ANY (Or Move) it will move from the clipboard to the explorer. It worked like a charm on MacOS X finder. Give it a try on Windows, I don't see why it would not work

Comment: Oh yes, I tried it again and it does work very well on Ubuntu. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Additionnaly, is there a way to delay the treatement of the drag and drop until the user actually release the gesture on another application? The files in my application are actually online, and I don't want to start downloading until I'm sure that the user wanted to perform a drag and drop to the system, instead of inside the application.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe you should create another topic just for this one. I can't imagine how you can manage to identify when to put your files on the DragBoard. You see, for one or for other this should be an easy task, since you can make your DragBoard global and set it's content only when the drag is done, but this approach is no good for your app since the target.onDragDropped will receive an empty dragboard to work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample source for an action listener on an ImageView image extraction to OS' explorer (With a custom process for jpg image to remove alpha-channel to display it correctly):

```
inputImageView.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler <MouseEvent>() {
               @Override
               public void handle(MouseEvent event) {


                   // for paste as file, e.g. in Windows Explorer
                    try {

            Clipboard clipboard Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();     
                   Dragboard db = inputImageView.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

                   ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();

                   Image sourceImage = inputImageView.getImage();

                   ImageInfo imageInfo = (ImageInfo) inputImageView.getUserData();

                   String name = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(imageInfo.getName());
                   String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(imageInfo.getName());


                   ///Avoid get "prefix lenght too short" error when file name lenght <= 3
                   if (name.length() < 4){
                       name = name+Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(Math.random()));;
                       }

                   File temp = File.createTempFile(name, "."+ext);

                   if (ext.contentEquals("jpg")|| ext.contentEquals("jpeg")){
                       BufferedImage image = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(sourceImage, null); // Get buffered image.
                       BufferedImage imageRGB = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(),
BufferedImage.OPAQUE);
                       Graphics2D graphics = imageRGB.createGraphics();
                       graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
                       ImageIO.write(imageRGB, ext, temp);
                       graphics.dispose();

                       ImageIO.write(imageRGB,
                               ext, temp);  

                   }else{

                       ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(sourceImage, null),
                               ext, temp);  
                   }




                   content.putFiles(java.util.Collections.singletonList(temp));
                   db.setContent(content);
                   clipboard.setContent(content);
                   event.consume();

                   temp.deleteOnExit();

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                           System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                     }

               }
           });
```

With the help of use of an Object that is passed to the imageView's setUserData method, it helps me to retrieve database id and pic name:

```
  public class ImageInfo {
    private String imageInfo;
    private int inputId;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return imageInfo;
    }

    public ImageInfo(String imageInfo, int inputId) {
        this.imageInfo = imageInfo;
        this.inputId = inputId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return imageInfo;
    }

    public void setName(String imageInfo) {
        this.imageInfo = imageInfo;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return inputId;
    }

    public void setIndex(int areaindex) {
        this.inputId = inputId;
    }
}
```

I hope it will help somenone at an expected time :-)

Regards